# How to exit current item and stay in containing item in XWiki?

Tags: xwiki

Is it possible in XWiki Syntax 2.x to add subitems and then return to the containing item?

What I want is:

```
1. item 1 which might continue for several lines
   and which get lined up correctly base on the list
   thing:
    * sub1 of item 1
    * sub2 of item 1
   Continuing with item 1, but not inside sub2.
2. item 2 continues the list.
```

I have

```
1. Item 1
1*. sub1
1*. sub2
anything here is part of sub2. If I skip a line, I leave the outer list.
```

So, is this possible in the wiki syntax or do I have to use HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible using a group:

```
1. Item 1(((
* sub1
* sub2

anything here is part of sub2. If I skip a line, I leave the outer list.
)))
1. item 2 continues the list.
```

See http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/XWikiSyntax?syntax=2.1&section=Groups for the full syntax + other examples.